# ASP.NET : EF 5.X - Access Level Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to accumulate data which I can use as a reference between another database however, when I try to gather the data inside the row and store it in an array, I receive this error:

> CS0122: 'System.Nullable.value' is inaccessible due to its protection level

My current code is:

```
    short pay_termsId = 0;
    var tbl_sales_del = (from c in db.tblacc_sales_tran_del 
                         where c.TransactionNo == tranNo select c)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
    if (tbl_sales_del != null 
                   && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbl_sales_del.Vatdiscount.ToString()))
    {
        pay_termsId = tbl_sales_del.PaymentTermsID.value;
    }
```

I have tried to `var` the `pay_termsId` but I recieve the same error. Could anyone please reference me anything that could be useful to try to fix this? Much appreciated.

Comment: Which line is causing the problem?

Comment: `pay_termsId = tbl_sales_del.PaymentTermsID.value;` is causing the error @PeterSmith

Comment: Are you sure PaymentTermsID is not null?

Comment: I will do a check for that now but it shouldn't be @tede24

Comment: No, it is not Null ever and I've added a check just incase @tede24

Comment: If what you want is getting the value of a nullable, it's ".Value" no ".value"

Comment: Also try this: "PaymentTermsID??0"

Comment: that fixed it - thank-you. Could you post an answer with a reference to the difference? I searched ages for this stuff and found nothing worth reading. @tede24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at you class definitions. You probably need to change the member protection level of `PaymentTermsID` to `public`

In addition, if you are getting a `null` value you will need to do something like

```
pay_termsId = tbl_sales_del.PaymentTermsID.value ?? 0;
```

Or make `pay_termsId` of type `short?`

Comment: `pay_termsId = tbl_sales_del.PaymentTermsID.value ?? 0;` fixed the issue, thank-you also!

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo: it's .Value (capitalized)

Also, you could do this

```
PaymentTermsID??0
```

Which checks if id it's null then takes 0